# Is there a way to set all of an element or all of an area as one class?

Tags: html, css

I need to set all of the 'a' elements in a 'div' element as one class. Is there a way to do this using the 'div' element, some other element, or possibly CSS, or no? I am fairly new to HTML.

```
<ol id='list'><div class="column"><base class="animals">
    <li><a href=""><p>yes</p></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><p>yeah</p></a></li>
    </base>
    </div>
</ol>
```

My first thought was to use the base element but nothing really carried over.

I'm trying to make a search bar mechanism and I need all a elements to be as one class to comply with the JS:

```
function search_animal() {
  let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value;
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName('animals');
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
      x[i].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      x[i].style.display = "list-item";
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You'd want to use javascript or html to adjust the classnames. Can you clarify _why_ you're doing this? There may be a better solution, such as `#list *` in a css selector, which would work similarly without actually giving classnames to elements. I'm also unclear on what "use the base element" and "nothing [...] carried over" mean, can you clarify?

Comment: The question is confusing in a way that strongly suggests you're using the wrong terminology for whatever it is you're trying to do.  Can you include a specific example of what your end goal is here, so we can better understand what you need?  Are you trying to *style* those `a` elements? Or do you literally need to change their classnames (and if so, why?)

Comment: I'm trying to make a search bar mechanism and I need all `a` elements to be as one class to comply with the JS:

    `function search_animal() {
    let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
    input=input.toLowerCase();
    let x = document.getElementsByClassName('animals');
      
    for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) { 
        if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {
            x[i].style.display="none";
        }
        else {
            x[i].style.display="list-item";                 
        }
    }
}`

Comment: Also, by 'use the base element' and 'nothing carried over' I meant using this element: `<base>` to set a class (`<base class="animals">`) and it didn't work out very well since it affected more than just the `a` element

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, OL/UL are allowed LI as children, not base/div etc. And base shouldn't be used like that too.

I updated your HTML so it is correct, I also removed the p tags as they are meant to be used for paragraph text.

for referencing all of the anchor tags via CSS, you can use **#list a** as the space automatically references matching "children".

**UPDATE**
With the new information, I updated my answer to include an improved javascript search function.

You can loop through elements from querySelectorAll and pass selectors without needing a specific class.

I also updated the javascript to toggle an active class to hide/show the results.

```js
function search_animal() {
  let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  let links = document.querySelectorAll('#list li');
  
  links.forEach((e) => {
    e.classList.toggle("active",e.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(input))
  });
}

let searchbar = document.querySelector("#searchbar");
searchbar.addEventListener("input",search_animal);
```

```css
li{
  display:none;
}

li.active{
  display:list-item;
}
```

```html
<input placeholder="Enter in search text here" id="searchbar">
<div class="column">
  <ol id='list'>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        yes
      </a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="">
        yeah
      </a>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: this is good but do you know if there's a way to modify all of an element's class in CSS somehow or probably JS?

Comment: @reeman3000 I updated my answer. Knowing now that you are trying to reference via javascript, you can use querySelectorAll("#list li"). I simplified your javascript too

Answer (score 0):

if you want change styles of a tags inside the div (notice that your div has 'column' class) you can add following script in your css:

`.column a { /* here will be css styles */ }`

with mentioned selector you can change every a tag in the div.

Comment: farad this is good but I don't know how to change an element's class in CSS, I only know how to identify it using .[class]

Comment: create <style></style> in <head></head> of your HTML then write scripts between style tags

Comment: @reeman3000 this doesn't change the element classes; it lets you target those elements _without needing to_ change their classes.

Comment: @DanielBeck CSS can't change classes. That's not what CSS does.

Comment: reeman3000 edited his question, I answered his first question but now, there need be another answer

Answer (score 0):

To set the class of an `<a>` element, simply add `class="your_class"` to your `<a>` element. I would also suggest removing the `<p>` element from your `<a>` element.

```
<a href="" class="your_class">yes</a>
```

Additionally, the `<base>` element is not a correct element. I would also move the `<div>`s outside the ordered list.

```
<ol id="list">
    <li><a class="your_class" href="">yes</a></li>
    <li><a class="your_class" href="">yeah</a></li>
</ol>
```

Comment: this is guiding me more toward the answer but I tried setting the `<div>` element's class and it didn't work well because of something with the JS:

    `function search_animal() {     let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value     input=input.toLowerCase();     let x = document.getElementsByClassName('animals');            for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {          if (!x[i].innerHTML.toLowerCase().includes(input)) {             x[i].style.display="none";         }         else {             x[i].style.display="list-item";                          }     } }`

Answer (score 0):

JS Example:

```
`function search_animal() {
  let input = document.getElementById('searchbar').value
  input = input.toLowerCase();
  let links = document.querySelectorAll('#list li');
  
  links.forEach((e) => {
    e.classList.toggle("active",e.innerText.toLowerCase().includes(input))
  });
}

let searchbar = document.querySelector("#searchbar");
searchbar.addEventListener("input",search_animal);`
```

Instead of trying to set the element as one class directly, find the parent element and get what it includes (the initial element you were trying to set as a class), then modify the parent element primarily using JS.